# Difference between two regex: "([^"]*)" vs "(.*?)"

Tags: regex

I am learning about using cucumber's step defintion, which use regex.  I came across the following different usages and would like to know if there's some material difference between the two approaches of capturing a group within a pair of double quotes:

approach one: `"([^"]*)"`

approach two: `"(.*?)"`

For example, consider a string input: `'the output should be "pass!"'`.  Both approaches would capture `pass!`.  Are there inputs where two the approaches capture differently; or are they equivalent?

Thanks

Comment: Other than what is explained in the answers already, an important difference (although not, I feel, important enough for its own answer) is that the lazy pattern (#2) is quite a bit less efficient in most - if not all - regex engines. Which doesn't mean it's necessarily *slower* - that depends on various engine optimizations as well as your actual matches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, in naked eye they look same. But slight different. Have a look on this example:

input:

```
a " regex
example is
here" please
```

Output for `"([^"]*)"`:

```
 regex
example is
here
```

And, Output for `"(.*?)"` is empty.

`.*?` means any character except `\n` (0 or more times), and there has few newlines between the quotes(`"`). If we use this in regex we need to give the regex engine a hint to use `Multiline` matching.

Comment: I think it's worth emphasizing here (because someone reading this answer who is less well-versed in regexes than Sabuj might not catch it) the fact that `"(.*?)"` is *non-greedy*, and so (like the explicit `[^"]` in this case) will also not match on any `"` characters *within* the (potential) capture-group.

Comment: That's not Multiline mode you're talking about, it's Singleline (also known as DOTALL mode in some flavors).  Multiline mode is the one that alters the meaning of the anchors (`^` and `$`), which he's not using.

Answer (score 3):

`"([^"]*)"` will also capture newlines, so if you have

```
"Something
that goes on two lines"
```

then it will match it.

`"(.*?)"` does not span newlines, so it will *not* match that phrase.

Unless you use the single-line modifier `(?s)`. In which case `.` will also include newline characters. The following expression: `(?s)"(.*?)"` would then match and capture.

Answer (score 3):

### Difference between `"(.*?)"` and `"([^"]*)"`

It depends upon where this regex fragment appears within the larger context of the overall pattern. It also depends upon the target string that is being searched. For example, given the following input string:

`'foo "quote1" bar "quote2"'`

The expression: `/"(.*?)"$/` (note the added end of string anchor) will match: `"quote1" bar "quote2"` but the `/"([^"]*)"$/` expression will match: `"quote2"`.

The dot will match a double quote if it has to to get a successful overall match.